# Is information gain only calculated using decrease in entropy of a dataset?

Tags: decision-trees, entropy, information-gain, gini-impurity

Is information gain only calculated using decrease in entropy of a dataset?

If I calculate it using the decrease in Gini Impurity, before and after the split, can it not be considered information gain?

Answer (score 1):

Information gain is a very specific measure in information theory, thus the entropy definition... for sure, the decrease in Gini index can be seen as a proxy for it